# Proof of Double Expectation of a Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability

There is a proof of 
$$
E(E(Y|x)) = E(Y)
$$
$Proof:$

WLOG, suppose X and Y are two continuous random variables.

Let $E(Y|x)=m(x) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} yf(y|x)\, dy$

Then 
$$
E(E(Y|x))=E(m(x))= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} m(x) f(x) \, dx =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Big(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} yf(y|x)\, dy\Big) f(x)\, dx
$$
$$
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y\frac{f(x,y)}{f(x)}f(x)\, dy \, dx 
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} yf(x,y)\, dy \, dx = E(Y)
$$

My question is why $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} yf(x,y)\, dy \, dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} yf(y)\, dy=E(Y)$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the order of integration and use that the marginal density can be obtained via
$$
f(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx.
$$

The "WLOG" statement is however a bit odd, since there is lost a lot of generality by assuming $(X,Y)$ to be continuous (which by the way is different from assuming that $X$ and $Y$ marginally are continuous random variables).

Comment: Ok,I got it. Can I directly omit to say which kind of variables X and Y are ?

Comment: You can, but that requires a different, more general definition of the conditional expectation ${\rm E}[Y\mid X]$ (one not using densities, of course). Are you familiar with such?